# UISwitch set default value to OFF when start app for the first time

Tags: ios, null, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have a UISwitch which is used to mute the sound effects with.
When switch is set ON the sound effects are mute.
The state is saved using NSUserDefaults. It works great. But when the app is started from the very first time after installing it, and you got to the settings and the switch is set to OFF but there is no sound. But if i press the switch on then off again the sound effect works.

How do i do to set switch default value to OFF.

I have seen similar exempels but i don't get it to work.

In the first ViewController i have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"]==nil)
    {
        [[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"] isEqual: @"off"];
    }

    if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"] isEqual: @"off"]) {

        ImageViewLjud.hidden = YES;

    }

}
```

and in the settings ViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

self->switchOutletLjud.on = ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"]

                              isEqualToString:@"On"]) ? (YES) : (NO);


if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"] isEqual: @"On"]) {

    [ImageViewLjud setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ljudOFF.png"]];
}

else {

    [ImageViewLjud setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ljudON.png"]];
}
}
```

and this is the switch

```
- (IBAction)switchLjudChanged:(UISwitch *)sender {

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if (sender.on == 0) {

    [standardDefaults setObject:@"Off" forKey:@"switchKeyLjud"];

} else if (sender.on == 1) {

    [standardDefaults setObject:@"On" forKey:@"switchKeyLjud"];

}

if ([[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"] isEqual: @"On"]) {

    [ImageViewLjud setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ljudOFF.png"]];
}

else {

    [ImageViewLjud setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ljudON.png"]];
}

    [standardDefaults synchronize];

}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a very simple error in your sample code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"]==nil)
{
    [[standardDefaults stringForKey:@"switchKeyLjud"] isEqual: @"off"];
}
```

The logic in this case doesn't actually set the "off" key, you're only evaluating it. First you check if it's nil. If it's nil, then you check if it is equal to "off". If it's nil, it can't also be equal to "off". I think what you want to be doing, in the event that it is initially nil, is then setting it to off:

```
[standardDefaults setString:@"off" forKey:@"switchKeyLjud"];
```

Looks like a simple typo.

Additionally, consider setting the `BOOL` values directly in your user defaults, rather then relying on strings and then translating those back and forth to `BOOL` values in code. Unless you have a specific need to store them as strings in `NSUserDefaults`, avoid the additional point of failure.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, i saw that i post the wrong code for first ViewController, in the ViewDidLoad, i don't have the first "if statement". Regards Daniel